# How to set css position absolute for Firefox and Chrome and relative for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, position

What is the IE hack for setting the position property : relative in "not-a-browser"IE and position : absolute in other browsers (FireFox, Chrome)..

Thanks everyone..!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) in the `<head>` to send different versions of IE different 'hack' stylesheets. That way I can keep my main css file clean. Make sure you include the IE stylesheets after your main stylesheets.

Comment: can we use the conditional comments in a .css file?

Comment: No, you have to give 2 seperate CSS files, one for all browsers, and for for IE hacks.

Answer (score 4):

Hi Here is a Sheet about CSS hack for different browser:

```
            IE6  IE7  IE8  FireFox  Chrome
    _        Y    N    N      N       N
    *        Y    Y    N      N       N
!important   N    Y    Y      Y       Y
----------
    \9       Y    Y    Y      N       N
```

I think if you want a hack for IE/None-IE, you can set \9 at the end of your css attribute. Comment: Sorry, it's too hard to make a sheet in the editor.

e.g.

```
.test{

position:absolute;/* This is for all browser*/

position:relative\9;/* This will be only supported for IE6/7/8 and will overrider the up position attribute

}
```

Sorry, I'm not familliar with this editor, it's really hard to make the answer looks better.

Comment: What? Could you give a bit more information? An example maybe?

Answer (score 1):

shortest way to do this:

```
.myStyle {
  position:absolute
  _position:relative
}
```

Although possibly not the cleanest...